# How to declare parameters inside a function in java to receive images like python self?

Tags: java, python, opencv, image-processing

I'm new to both java and python. I can't figure how to pass image files in a java function. In case of python I used self. The following is my python code

**img.py**

```
 def initialize(self, img1, img2):
     self.imgDiff = 1
     self.img1 = img1
     self.img2 = img2
```

How do I do this on Java?

Comment: What should be the types for the parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java you don't need the `self` as an argument. Also, for the other `self`s, replace them for `this`.

Like so:

```
void initialize(Image img1, Image img2) {
    this.img1 = img1;
    this.img2 = img2;
}
```

This is dependent on the type of image of course.